# How do I insert into database with codeigniter without it putting the single quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm making a feature in my app where users can select multiple db items and change the department they belong to all at once.  I have this in my codeigniter model currently:

```
function  multimove($dept, $jobstring)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE Jobs set department = ? where id IN(?)";
    $this->db->query($sql, array($jobstring, $dept)); 
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

The function takes in two values which is the department number and the id's of the selected jobs.
I'm trying to achieve this SQL function:

```
UPDATE Jobs set department = 3 where id IN(5,6,48);
```

But codeigniter generates this:

```
UPDATE Jobs set department = '3' where id IN('5,6,48');
```

It puts single quotes on my values and it creates errors.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Code won't be as nice, but you can always do `"...department = " . $dept .  " where id..."`.

Comment: I don't use codeigniter, but I think you'd have a placeholder for each value, then separate out the `csv`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help!  It looks like just stringing it all together was able to make it work.  This is what ended up with:

```
function  multimove($dept, $jobstring)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE Jobs set department = " . $jobstring . " WHERE id IN(" . $dept . ")";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Calling to model

```
$this->load->model('Model_jobs');
$this->Model_jobs->multimove(3,'2,3,8');
```

### Model

```
function multimove($dept,$jobstring)
{   
    $ids = explode(",",$jobstring);
    $upd_data = array('department' => $dept );
    $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
    $this->db->update('test', $upd_data); 
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `trim();`

```
$trim_var = trim($var, "'");
```

Comment: I've actually tried this in several different ways.  Codeigniter still overwrites it and puts in the single quotes...

Answer (score 0):

set() will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE (CI documentation).
This should be what you want. Pass $jobstring as a string like '(5,6,48)'
For example in your controller:

```
$this->my_model->multimove(3, '(5,6,48)');
```

And in your model:

```
    function  multimove($dept, $jobstring)
    {
      $query = $this
      ->db
      ->set('department', $dept, FALSE)
      ->where('id in ', $jobstring, FALSE)
      ->update('Jobs');           
    }
```

Although I would not recommend this solution.